# Bad request with json

Tags: json

I am receiving bad request response code (400 for URL) when I am trying to send a json object. I believe I am not passing json object correctly but cannot find where I am doing a mistake.

```
   JSONObject actiontype = new JSONObject();
   JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
   JSONObject fields = new JSONObject();
   JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
   actiontype.put("type", "customer");
   actiontype.put("action", "create");
   record.put("id", "C004");
   fields.put("{customerType", "Individual");
   fields.put("account", "12345");
   fields.put("prefix", "Mr");
   fields.put("id", "C004");
   fields.put("name", "Deckson and Company Pvt Ltd");
   fields.put("firstName", "Deckson");
   fields.put("lastName", "Company");
   fields.put("email", "test@rcl.lk");
   fields.put("telephone", "11235468792");
   fields.put("ext", "111");
   fields.put("class", "Architecture");
   fields.put("paymentMethod", "creditcard");
   fields.put("invoiceType", "");
   fields.put("vat", "VAT12345");
   fields.put("svat}", "SVAT54321");

   address.put("{country", "Sri Lanka");
   address.put("address", "Rocell");
   address.put("street", "No. 20 R.A De Mel Mawatha");
   address.put("city", "Colombo");
   address.put("postalCode", "003300");
   address.put("province", "Western Province");
   address.put("isDefaultShipping", true);
   address.put("isDefaultBilliing", true);
   address.put("isResidential}", false);

   record.put("record", address);

   record.put("record", fields);

   actiontype.put("body", record);
```

I am expecting to form following json:

```
{
    "type": "customer",
    "action": "create",
    "record": {
        "id": "C001",
        "fields": {
            "customerType": "Individual",
            "account": "21631",
            "prefix": "Mr",
            "id": "C001",
            "name": "Test Customer from Postman",
            "firstName": "fN",
            "lastName": "lN",
            "email": "dekard.shaw@rocell.com",
            "telephone": "94775263148",
            "ext": "3722",
            "class": "Architecture",
            "paymentMethod": "creditcard",
            "invoiceType": "",
            "vat": "VAT21523",
            "svat": "SVAT21526"
        },
        "address": [
            {
                "country": "Sri Lanka",
                "address": "Mr Deckard Shaw",
                "street": "No 20, R. A. De Mel Mawatha",
                "city": "Colombo",
                "postalCode": "00300",
                "province": "Western Province",
                "isDefaultShipping": true,
                "isDefaultBilling": false,
                "isResidential": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the app, nobody can help you I'm afraid. Please tell us more: Error messages?

Comment: I am using a rest api for which I am passing json but response is not successful. Below is the error message:Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://5358165.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=7&deploy=1

Comment: Remove the braces from the String literals and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a bunch of mistakes:

```
fields.put("{customerType", "Individual");  // You have a rogue { here.
fields.put("svat}", "SVAT54321");  // You have a rogue } here.
address.put("{country", "Sri Lanka");  // You have a rogue { here.
address.put("isResidential}", false);  // You have a rogue } here.
record.put("record", fields);  // This should be "fields", not "record".
actiontype.put("body", record);  // This should be "record", not "body".
```

There's also an issue here:

```
record.put("record", address);
```

For one, this should be `"address"`, not `"record"`.  Additionally, the value needs to be an array, not an object.  I don't know what language you're using, but I assume you'll want something that looks like this:

```
record.put("address", new JSONObject[] { address });
```

Or maybe this:

```
JSONArray addresses = new JSONArray();
addresses.put(address);
record.put("address", addresses);
```

You should take a closer look at the output JSON that you're producing to ensure there aren't more mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot I followed your suggestion and this time it completed successfully.